# Removing Symfony2 scope widening notice

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony, scope

I'm trying to speed up my stack by removing references to the service container where possible. In this case I only need the request:

```
email_error_message:
  class: Core\MyBundle\Services\Email\ErrorMessage
        arguments: [ @request, %params ]
```

However, that throws a scope widening issue. I'm not concerned with refactoring the code for now, I just wish to get rid of the warning by adding strict = true. But I can't seem to get the YAML syntax right:

```
email_error_message:
  class: Core\MyBundle\Services\Email\ErrorMessage
        arguments:
            - { type: service, id: request, strict: false }
            - %params%
```

This isn't working though. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I realise I could change the scope of this service to request, but that isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to restrict the scope of the service to the `request` scope, since you need to make sure you're passed the right `Request` instance - if you are using the service from within a subrequest for example, or whether through the main request.  Adjust your service config to:

```
services:
    email_error_message:
        class: Core\MyBundle\Services\Email\ErrorMessage
        scope: request
        arguments: [ @request, %params% ]
```

See [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#setting-the-scope-in-the-definition) for more details.

**Edit** as per your question edit, you're not able to change the scope. In which case, your syntax should be as follows:

```
services:
    email_error_message:
        class: Core\MyBundle\Services\Email\ErrorMessage
        arguments: [ @request=, %params% ]
```

with the appended `=` symbol. Note that I've not seen this referenced anywhere, and it's from digging around in the code for the DI container ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I did read that, but can't do it unfortunately; it will impact on a lot of services further down the line whose scope I don't want to change (I'll update my question to reflect this)

Comment: Please note that `@request=` syntax does not work in Twig's `globals` configuration (it's throwing `ServiceNotFoundException`). Only way I found to inject service with wider scope to Twig's globals is `$this->controller->get('twig')->addGlobal('A', $this->controller->get('B'));` handled in request listener!